# Disable last:child when have only one item

Tags: jquery, list

I'm using this code to add class for list items:

```
jQuery('#news ul > li:first-child').addClass('first');
jQuery('#news ul > li:last-child').addClass('last');
```

It's working very well. The problem is when I have only one item...the code is adding the two classes for the same li.

Example:

1. Works perfectly if exist two or more items:

   ```
   <div id="nav">
   <ul>
   <li class="first">Item 1</li>
   <li class="last">Item 2</li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   ```
2. Add the two classes for the unique item:

   ```
   <div id="nav">
   <ul>
   <li class="first last">Item 1</li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   ```

Is there a way to disable .last class if is only one item?

Thanks!

Comment: `jQuery('#news ul > li:last-child:not(:first-child)').addClass('last');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `:only-child` selector:

```
$('#news ul > li:last').not(':only-child').addClass('last');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#news ul > li:first').addClass('first');
$('#news ul > li:last').not('.first').addClass('last');
```

Answer (score 4):

why not just handle this with CSS?

```
#news ul > li.last { }

#news ul > li.first,
#news ul > li.first.last { }
```

Comment: Because I want a cross-browser solution.

Comment: @user1226062 he is saying once you add the classes, handle them with css. This would be crossbrowser.